# C# - deserialization from JSON, result is always an empty object

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I try to read an object in c# from a JSON string - but the result is always an empty object without any exception - but I don't see an error

The JSON string that I get from a webservice is

```
{  
   "CustomUserFields":{
   },
   "CustomApplicationFields":{    
   },
   "Attachments":[    
   ],
   "Tags":[    
   ],
   "HasModifyEntriesAccess":true,
   "HasViewEntryContentsAccess":true,
   "CommentPrompts":{  
      "AskForCommentOnViewPassword":false,
      "AskForCommentOnViewOffline":false,
      "AskForCommentOnModifyEntries":false,
      "AskForCommentOnMoveEntries":false,
      "AskForCommentOnMoveFolders":false,
      "AskForCommentOnModifyFolders":false
   },
   "Id":"c51ca807-9e01-4652-95d0-645a0914b1ba",
   "Name":"SecondOne",
   "Username":"Second@test.domain",
   "Password":null,
   "Url":"",
   "Notes":"Bla Bla Bla",
   "GroupId":"1182570d-d22d-4f2a-babb-3dab4ff48852",
   "Created":"2018-02-27T14:39:15+01:00",
   "Modified":"2018-02-27T14:39:15+01:00",
   "Expires":null,
   "UsageComment":null
}
```

My code looks like this

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serF = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Credential));
Credential cred1 = new Credential();
MemoryStream msF = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response2.Content));
cred1 = serF.ReadObject(msF) as Credential;
msF.Close();

[Serializable, XmlRoot("Credential"), DataContract(Name = "Credential")]
public class Credential
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid id = Guid.Empty;
    [DataMember]
    public Guid groupid = Guid.Empty;
    [DataMember]
    public string name = String.Empty;
}
```

I removed some properties from the class to simplfy reading the code - but that makes no difference

The Credential object cred1 has always empty attributes

Comment: Not sure now, is the deserialization case-sensitive? Bcs. You've got properties in lower case & JSON as CamelCase.

Comment: You've used `response2` which is impossible to see the definition from your code, but shouldn't that be a request object?

Comment: Also use `using` blocks for streams to make sure everything will get closed / disposed so you would not introduce memory leaks if your not carefull

Answer (score 0):

C# Classes from your Json (Auto generated via: http://json2csharp.com/)
:

```
public class CustomUserFields
{
}

public class CustomApplicationFields
{
}

public class CommentPrompts
{
    public bool AskForCommentOnViewPassword { get; set; }
    public bool AskForCommentOnViewOffline { get; set; }
    public bool AskForCommentOnModifyEntries { get; set; }
    public bool AskForCommentOnMoveEntries { get; set; }
    public bool AskForCommentOnMoveFolders { get; set; }
    public bool AskForCommentOnModifyFolders { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public CustomUserFields CustomUserFields { get; set; }
    public CustomApplicationFields CustomApplicationFields { get; set; }
    public List<object> Attachments { get; set; }
    public List<object> Tags { get; set; }
    public bool HasModifyEntriesAccess { get; set; }
    public bool HasViewEntryContentsAccess { get; set; }
    public CommentPrompts CommentPrompts { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public object Password { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public object Expires { get; set; }
    public object UsageComment { get; set; }
}
```

Take a look to case sensitive